# matlab: subs on symbolic constant returns scalar instead of vector for a vector input

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

usually, symbolic functions return vectors for vector inputs:

```
syms('x');
f=x*2;
subs(f,[1 2 3])
outputs: [2 4 6]
```

but doing

```
f=sym('0');
subs(f,[1 2 3]);
outputs: 0
and not: [0 0 0]
```

so basically, my questions is how do I make `f` behave as a "normal" symbolic function.
I can do something ugly like `f=x-x` to create a function that always returns zero, but is there a prettier way?

Comment: Just in case someone else stumbles upon this: Works as expected in R2013a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no way.

`sym('0')` creates a symbolic constant (0, in this case).  `subs()` replaces all *variables* with each value from the given vector.  However, you have no variables, so `subs()` just returns the given symbolic constant.

It gets better.  `sym()` internally does some simplification, so `sym('0*x')` or `sym('x-x')` both become `sym('0')` and you get the exact same behavior.  Similarly, `sym('x/x')` turns into `sym('1')` and you just get the scalar 1 back from `subs()` even if you pass it a vector.

The only way you're going to get around this is by writing a helper function that detects if the `size()` of the output from `subs()` is less than the vector, and turns it into the correct size of a vector if needed.

Comment: I think you're wrong. I tried `sym('x-x')` and it did produce the desired effect.

Comment: @noam - I'm using R2009b, and verified this before I posted it.  If you're using something older, you might not want to depend on that behavior remaining if it's possible you'll end up updating your install.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the Symbolic Toolbox so this is a blind guess.  Your function declarations don't look identical enough:

```
syms('x');
f=x*2;
```

against

```
f=sym('0');
```

Perhaps what you have done in the first case is define a function which returns the double of its inputs, in the second case defined a function which returns 0 whatever its inputs.  Maybe

```
syms('x');
f=x*0;
```

is what you need ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I suggest you delete this suggestion... :)

Comment: Well, I had thought that posting a blind guess would so provoke a thundering heard of SO Matlabbers that you would have been overwhelmed with right answers by now.